# Presenting a view controller of custom size with navigation

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to present a view controller of custom size say (500,500). I try to do that with the below code, it works fine with a semi transparent light gray background if I present the view controller alone but when i put the view controller in a navigation controller (which I want to do) there is a black background that comes up, I dont want this and I want the gray one.

I did the following code with the help of this question:

[iOS -- how do you control the size of a modal view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231022/ios-how-do-you-control-the-size-of-a-modal-view-controller)

```
MyViewController *vc=[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

nav.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

CGRect r = CGRectMake(self.window.rootViewController.view.bounds.size.width/2 - 250,
                              self.window.rootViewController.view.bounds.size.height/2 - 250,
                              500, 500);
r = [self.window.rootViewController.view convertRect:r toView:vc.view.superview.superview];
  vc.view.superview.superview.frame = r;
```

Any guess, what I am missing here?? Or is there a easy way to present a custom size VC with navigation??

With navigation:

[image]

Without navigation: (i am using a dark background, so it may appear like it is black but it is not)
[image]

Comment: What's `vc.view.superview.superview.frame=r` for?

Comment: To reduce the frame of VC respective to its superview.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting transparent overlay on the view controller and present it, sothat it looks like as what you actually want...

Also refer the following link,

[Show modal view controller with custom frame in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065918/show-modal-view-controller-with-custom-frame-in-ipad)

[How to present a modal view controller with custom size in center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048301/how-to-present-a-modal-view-controller-with-custom-size-in-center)

[iPad custom size of modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298378/ipad-custom-size-of-modal-view-controller/10134726#10134726)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: Yeah i get you, but the thing is that I am getting a transparent view by default if I present a ViewController object and a black one when I am presenting a NavigaitonContoller with ViewController in it. Why is that so??

Comment: can you put the screenshot

Comment: kindly try like this `[self.navigationControler presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];` instead of `[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];`

Comment: I am doing all this universally so this controller can come up in any scree with a gesture. So i cannot user self.navigationController may be I would try self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.

Comment: which backgroundcolor?? window or the VC?