# How to add a view over a selected view controller in a TabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I had an application in which i had a tab bar controller with 4 navigation controllers.

```
_tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
_tabbarcontroller.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vcontroller,xnav,ynav,znav,nil];
```

and everything works fine. Now I want to add a view over the selected viewcontroller when the 0th item selected in the tab bar; this must be over the tabbarcontroller. What I tried:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [_tabbarcontroller.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

    if(tabBar.selectedItem==item0)
    {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex=selectedIndex;
        FViewController *fviewcontroller =[[FViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FViewController" bundle:nil];
        [_tabbarcontroller.view addSubview: fviewcontroller.view];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem right. I want it to be added over the present selected view controller and when selecting out side that small view needs to remove that also.  can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: What kind of view are you trying to display? Does it have multiple UIControl elements? Or, is it just to display static data?

Comment: @its a small view with 3 buttons ,by remaining as overlay...so that the background can be seen..

Comment: you may refer to this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9046159/2954866). I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve this is use Popup and display with the 0th index of your tabbar controller.
add this popup in 
tabbarcontroller.selectedViewController.view when selected index of tabbarcontroller is 0.

Comment: in the 0 th index the selected view controller always will be 0 th one